# How rollback to the previous version (from working to beta version) in google play console?

Tags: android, google-play, android-testing, google-play-console

I created my application and uploaded it into beta testing in google play console. After some tests, I updated it to the working version. But now I want to cancel the working version (which is available to everyone) and post a new beta.

How can i do this?

I hope you will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a version is live in production (live to everyone) you must always have a version which is live to everyone. This doesn't mean you can't have a new beta version. You just don't cancel the working version to do it.

There is [some documentation here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213).

The point of a beta version is to test a new version before it is available, not to immediately replace your working production version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I close the working version for downloads and leave only beta?

Comment: @BohdanMartynov - Not directly. You would need to create a DIFFERENT app ID for the beta, and then tell Google to stop publishing your original app. I don't know whether you can TEMPORARILY stop the original app, so that later you can re-publish a corrected version. Support person at Google can probably do this for you.